# Django distinct not working with Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm configuring an API to pull a list of results. The items are clothing 'Products', which have several 'Variations'.

I am trying to use *distinct* to make sure the queryset only returns a list of unique products- instead of the same product repeated several times due to many variations.

In the past, I used distinct on product's primary key (id). However, the below code is not working.

I get a 500 error when I try using "distinct". Without it- I get no error. I cannot test locally as SQLite does not like distinct. I am using

```
class InternalListView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        filters = {}
        for key, value in request.GET.items():
            key = key.lower()
            if key in countmatch:
                lookup, val = internalmatch[key](value.lower())
                filters[lookup] = val

        qset = (
            Product.objects
            .filter(**filters)
            .distinct('id')
            .order_by('-rating')
            .values('name', 'brand', 'rating')
            .annotate(
                price=F('variation__price__price'),
                id=F('pk'),
                vari=F('variation'),
            )
        )

        for i in qset:
            i['likes'] = random.randint(500, 1000)

        print qset

        return Response(qset.all())
```

Comment: Try to get hold of the error message underlying the 500 error and post the full stack trace of the exception if possible. But my guess is, the error message is "*SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions*". `distinct()` with field names is a [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) extension and only works when the fields given by `distinct()` are also supplied to the first `order_by()`.

Comment: In general I would really recommend installing a local Postgres server to try things out on when you're dealing with problems like this, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh just figured it out.

According to the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Both distinct & order_by have to be the same.

So this does NOT work:

```
        .distinct('id')
        .order_by('-rating')
```

But this WILL work:

```
        .distinct('id')
        .order_by('id')
```

And this works best:

```
        .distinct('rating', 'id')
        .order_by('-rating')
```

Anything wrong with using option 3?

Comment: `distinct('id')` translates to a `SELECT DISTINCT ON`, which is a [PostgreSQL extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). Since `distinct()` eliminates rows, PostgreSQL requires you to specify a defined order, as it would otherwise eliminate random rows, resulting in a (potentially) non-repeatable select.

Comment: It is a limitation, but it has to be a `subset` of the distinct columns and not identical (if so, thats django not pgsql).  `distinct` will only output the columns you asked for and therefore has no way to order on anything else.

Comment: @AndrewBacker Interestingly enough, PostgreSQL (9.4.6) only croaks when the order_by contains at least one column not in the distinct list. i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, b, c ... ORDER BY a` works. `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, b, c ... ORDER BY a, c` fails, while `SELECT DISTINCT ON (a, b) a, b, c ... ORDER BY a, b, c`. is accepted. That the first is accepted, looks wrong to me, though.  You get all three columns in the output, but in the first case, *first row* might be random.

Comment: @Ycon Option 3 is semantically different from the other two. `distinct('id')` will eliminate all rows with the same id. `distinct('id', 'rating')` only removes duplicate rows with the same `id` AND `rating`.

Comment: @dhke Interesting... I've not done a _lot_ of psql by hand, but I like this way of doing it actually.   It's a hack in TSQL.  I can see why #3 might work, but its just post-hoc rationalization.  Maybe it's already ordered by a & b so sure, we can do c now.. but if b isn't there, it gets confused.

Comment: So what do I have to do to actually eliminate duplicate results with duplicate IDs and still order by ranking? Using the third option does not help.